# Asymptotic behaviour of infinite sum over prime powers

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, asymptotics, goldbachs-conjecture

I am currently studying analytic number theory and my teacher suggested to ask here if the following sum

$S = \sum_{p} x^p = x^2 + x^3 + x^5 + x^7 + ...$

Where $p$ is a prime number is known and if it has an asymptotic behaviour. My motivation behind it relies on the following. If you square the sum

$S^2 = (\sum_{p} x^p)^2$

You get

$S^2 = \sum_{p,q} a_{p+q}x^{p+q}$

Where $p$ and $q$ are primes and $a_{p+q}$ is an integer.

It is not hard to see that Goldbach's conjecture is equivalent to claim that the $2k^{th}$ derivative of $S^2$ at $x=0$ is different than $0$, for all positive integer $k$.

My questions are the following:

1. Does $S$ have an asymptotic behavior?
2. Have there been attempts of proving Goldbach's conjecture trying to apply the circle method to $S^2$?

Thank you

Comment: Asymptotic for what $x$? Are you assuming that $|x| < 1$ ?

Comment: Yes. If the absolute value of $x$ is equal or greater than $1$ then the sum does not converge. The thing is that it looks like there shoud be an expression (or at least an approximation) to that infinite sum, right?

Comment: $S(x)$ has the unit circle as natural boundary, so it cannot be continued at any point there - not sure though if this has any relevance to what you are interested in as that seems to be more for $x$ near zero

Comment: Yes, for $x$ near zero.

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1, Since every primes $\ge 5$ are of the form $6k \pm 1$, by summing up the geometric sequences $x^{6k-1} + x^{6k+1}$ for $k = 1,2,\ldots, \infty$ and adding $x^{2} + x^{3}$, and taking advantage of the fact the the density of primes among the first few numbers of these form is high we get

$$
\sum_{p \ge 2} x^p = \frac{1 + x + x^3 + x^5 -x^6 - x^7}{x^4(x - x^7)} + O(x^{25})
$$